# How to import multiple files at a time in Datagridview using visual Basic

Tags: datagridview

I am new to Visual Basic.  I have a text box where I have path of multiple files, say four files. Each path is in a new line within the same text box.  I want to import data of these CSV or text files into a datagridview  with one click button.  I have been trying hard to achieve this goal but no success so far. The problem is that if I have path of one file in the text box, my application will run successfully. I have following code for click button to import data.

Dim TextFileReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(txtFilesPathHo.Text)

```
    TextFileReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
    TextFileReader.SetDelimiters(",", ";")

    'Now Create an empty table in the computer memory and declare necessary variables

    Dim TextFileTable As DataTable = Nothing


    Dim Column As DataColumn
    Dim Row As DataRow
    Dim UpperBound As Int32
    Dim ColumnCount As Int32
    Dim CurrentRow As String()




    'Use While Loop to readfile and create table

    While Not TextFileReader.EndOfData

        Try

            CurrentRow = TextFileReader.ReadFields()

            If Not CurrentRow Is Nothing Then

                'Check if the datatable has been created

                If TextFileTable Is Nothing Then

                    TextFileTable = New DataTable("TextFileTable")

                    'Get number of columns

                    UpperBound = CurrentRow.GetUpperBound(0)

                    'Create new columns in the datatable

                    For ColumnCount = 0 To UpperBound

                        Column = New DataColumn()

                        Column.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")
                        Column.ColumnName = "Column" & ColumnCount
                        Column.Caption = "Column" & ColumnCount
                        Column.ReadOnly = False
                        Column.Unique = False
                        TextFileTable.Columns.Add(Column)

                    Next

                End If


                Row = TextFileTable.NewRow
                For ColumnCount = 0 To UpperBound
                    Row("Column" & ColumnCount) = CurrentRow(ColumnCount).ToString
                Next

                TextFileTable.Rows.Add(Row)

            End If


        Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
            MsgBox("Line" & ex.Message & "is not valid and will be skipped")

        End Try


    End While


    'Now stop textfile reader
    TextFileReader.Dispose()

    'Copy data to datagridview

    DataGridViewHO.DataSource = TextFileTable




End Sub
```

Can anyone help me what changes in the above code should be made to load multiple files with one click.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it works, Hope can helps

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
' using multiple select of Openfiledialog

```
    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\temp\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.CSV"
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True

    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        For x = 0 To OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count
            Try
                Dim fName As String = ""
                fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(x)
                Me.TextBox1.Text += fName

                Dim TextLine As String = ""

                Dim SplitLine() As String

                If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then

                    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)

                    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

                        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()

                        SplitLine = Split(TextLine, "|")

                        Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)

                    Loop

                Else

                    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Next
    MsgBox("Total files loaded = " & OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count)
    End If

End Sub
```